# SwiftSoup parse JSON to HTML not found (Swift)

Tags: swift, parsing

how are you, I'm trying to convert the text of a JSON call that contains HTML code in visual format. That is to say that it shows the texts in bold and the line breaks instead of appearing the labels.

I am using Alamofire to request the information through JSON. But I can not encode the returned text and it appears in a label correctly as in Android I perform easily with `labeltexto.setText(Html.fromHtml("texthtmlcode"));`

The idea I have is using Swiftsoup but somehow or other it produces error. Do you have any other solution or idea?

```
self.labeltext.text = SwiftSoup.parse(resData[0]["texthtmlcode"].string)
```

As always thanks for your time and kindness.

Comment: What error do you get? I don't know about SwiftSoup, but if you want visual format, you should do `self.labeltext.attributedText = myParsedAndRenderedHTMLString` instead of `self.labeltext.text = myParsedAndRenderedHTMLString `.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to get text value

```
do{
    self.labeltext.text = try SwiftSoup.parse(resData[0]["texthtmlcode"].string).text()
    }catch{
    print(error)
  }
```